# angular 2 ngIf between 2 inputs

Tags: angular2-routing, jhipster, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I have this code `Html` for my view of an angular 2 form :

```
        <select class="form-control" name="medicamentid"   
       [(ngModel)]="demandemedicamentvff.medicamentid">
        <option *ngFor="let medicament of medicaments ;trackBy: 
        trackId" [value]="medicament.nom">{{medicament.nom}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label"  
        for="field_quatite">Quatite</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="quatite" 
        id="field_quatite"
            [(ngModel)]="demandemedicamentvff.quatite"
         />
    </div>
```

I want if the value selected is equal to one of `medicament.nom` stored in database the the max on the second input is equal to 'medicament.quantity' .
I didn't find a solution as i am beginner .
Thank you in advance for helping me .

Answer (score 0):

you may use ng-containers and ngIf

```
<ng-container *ngIf="medicament.nom == value_selected">
   {{Call_funtion()}}
</ng-container>
```